# Querying JSON in POSTGRESQL returns NONE everytime

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

jsonb column *text_results* contains values in the following form :
{'Name' : 'john doe' , 'id' : '123'}

On querying

`Select text_results->>'Name' as Name from user_master`

or

`Select json_extract_path_text(text_results::json,'Name') as name from user_master`

it always return *None* without any error even though values are present.

Need help with rectifying the error or any other way of extracting values from json column in POSTGRESQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your real json, the valid one. Single quotes ' are't valid. Both queries should work fine, it does over here when I use a valid json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works as expected provided that [JSON syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) is correct using double quotes. Here is an illustration.

```sql
with user_master(text_results) as 
(
 values ('{"Name": "john doe", "id": 123}'::jsonb)
)
select text_results->>'Name' as Name from user_master;

-- john doe
```

Comment: Yes, the data was incoming in 'single quotes' hence I was facing this issue.